# Trying to add backslash in C# as escape for MySql insert statement

Tags: c#, mysql

I am importing and Excel spreadsheet in order to insert into a MySql database. Here's one record in the spreadsheet:

```
Loc     Item                 Description
FAB12   0121G00667PDG   PNL  DUCT 27.5"
```

I'm using `OleDbDataReader` to get a `DataTable` and that is working. The problem I'm having is when trying to replace the `"` with `\"` so that MySql will accept the double quote. I am trying to get C# to change `27.5"` to `27.5\"`

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Here's the result I'm getting now:

```
INSERT INTO test_table2 (Loc, Item, Description) VALUES ("FAB12  
 ","0121G00667PDG","PNL  DUCT 27.5"")
```

Here's the code:

```
           for (int i = 0; i < dtSheet.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dtSheet.Rows[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < dtSheet.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                DataColumn dc = dtSheet.Columns[j];
                if (dr[j].ToString().Contains("\""))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dr[j].ToString());
                    dr[j].ToString().Replace("\"", "\\\""); 
                  //need the backslash for mysql to escape " 
                  //so trying to get "PNL  DUCT 27.5\""
                    Console.WriteLine(dr[j].ToString());
                }
```

Here's the fix as per Majid. Using prepared statement allowed the double quotes to be inserted into MySql
     try
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Connection = conn;

```
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test_table2 (Loc, Item, Description) VALUES( @Loc, @Item, @Desc )";
            cmd.Prepare();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Loc", "Loc");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item", "Item");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Desc", "Desc");

            foreach (DataRow row in dtSheet.Rows)
            {
                cmd.Parameters["@Loc"].Value = row[0];
                cmd.Parameters["@Item"].Value = row[1];
                cmd.Parameters["@Desc"].Value = row[2];
                Console.WriteLine(cmd.ToString());

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Comment: **DON'T DO IT**. Use [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx) instead.

Comment: I tried that too. As per my comment to @Koby it's not working either. Not sure why, but either method won't add a back slash.

Comment: With a parameterized query there is no need to add a backslash. Anyway, by any chance you missing that string is inmutable (Only the return value will be replaced)? But again, use parameters instead.

Comment: you're correct @Majid, it worked and I didn't have to add an escape character for MySql. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
dr[j].ToString().Replace("\"", @"\");
```

Comment: I tried that and get the same result. I'm not sure what's going on. Nothing seems to change the result of the replace. I even tried: .Replace("\"",@"x"); But get nothing different in the output sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters or this `value.Replace("\\","\\\\")`